# How can i read text from JText to main method of the same class?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm at loss here.

I need to get text from JText field? save it as a string and later use it in the main method of the same class. I'm getting the mistake

> non-static variable file cannot be referenced from a static context

but the method main must remain static and i can do nothing with the field, because i uce standart NetBeans tools to make JFrame application.

```
    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String name = jTextField1.getText();
     file = new File( path+"\\"+name+".txt" );
}
```

Please help!

P.S. This is the entire class

```
package holtwinters;

import static holtwinters.HoltWinters.sum;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
String path = "C:\\Users\\Jane\\Desktop";
File file;


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextField1.setText("Введите номер банкомата");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Ввести");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 280, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(136, 136, 136)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String name = jTextField1.getText();
     file = new File( path+"\\"+name+".txt" );
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

 /*  public void run(){
        String name = jTextField1.getText();

}
  */ 

public static void main(String args[]) 
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */

    new NewJFrame();


//    new NewJFrame().run();
    new NewJFrame().jTextField1ActionPerformed(null);


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream( file ), "UTF-8"
            )
    );
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {



        try {
            Long y = Long.valueOf(line);
           // System.out.println(y);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Неверный формат строки!");
        }
    }

  //  long data = Long.valueOf(line);
  //  int change = (int) data;
  //  long [] y = new long [change];

    int period = 24;
    int m = 5;

    long[] y = new long[144];
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path+"\\"+name+".txt"));

        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLong()) {

            y[i] = scanner.nextLong();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double sum_origin = 0;
    int k=0;
    do {
        sum_origin = sum_origin + y[k];
        k++;
    } while (k<24);

//searching for alpha
    double alpha = 0.01;
    double a = 0.01;
    double x=sum_origin;
    double q;
    do {
        double beta = 0.3;
        double gamma = 0.3;
        double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, a, beta, gamma,
                period, m);
        double sum_pre = sum(prediction);

          q = sum_origin - sum_pre;
        if (q<=x) {
            x=q;
            alpha = a;
        }
        a = a +0.01;
    } while (a<0.99);

//searching for beta
    double beta = 0.01;
    double b = 0.01;
    double x1=1000000;
    double q1;
    do {
        double gamma = 0.3;
        double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, alpha, b, gamma,
                period, m);
        double sum_pre = sum(prediction);
        q1 = sum_origin - sum_pre;
        if (q1<=x1) {
            x1=q1;
            beta = b;
        }
        b = b +0.01;
    } while (b<0.99);

//searching for gamma
    double gamma = 0.01;
    double g = 0.01;
    double x2=1000000;
    double q2;
    do {
        double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, alpha, beta, g,
                period, m);
        double sum_pre = sum(prediction);
        q2 = sum_origin - sum_pre;
        if (q2<=x2) {
            x2=q2;
            gamma = g;
        }
        g = g +0.01;
    } while (g<0.99);


  //  System.out.println(alpha);
  //  System.out.println(beta);
  //  System.out.println(gamma);


    double[] prediction = HoltWinters.forecast(y, alpha, beta, gamma,
            period, m);
   for(int i = period; i <= prediction.length - 1; i++) {
           System.out.println(prediction[i] + "  ");
    }
    br.close();


    File flt = new File("C:\\Users\\Jane\\Desktop\\"+name+"_prediction.txt");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(flt)));
    for(int i = period; i <= prediction.length - 1; i++) {
        out.println(prediction[i] + "  ");
    }

    out.flush();


    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: @Radiodef it makes forecast using Holt_winters method

Comment: How is it supposed to work, though? Basically, you shouldn't be doing all that stuff you're doing in `main`. It looks like all the file IO in `main` should be done when a button is clicked or something like that. You need to put it in an event. Unlike a console program, Swing is event-based. You should probably look through the tutorials to learn more. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: @Radiodef thank you!! you advice helped me soooo much!!! I've understood my mistake in how i made my programms!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you trying to do from the program:

- Once the user interface is initialized, you want to take some input from user (through `JTextField`) and that input is supposed to be file name
- And by reading that file name you want to construct File object.

If what I think you want to is correct, then you can achieve that by using button's clicked event also
Instead of using anonymous inner class  for button action listener you can implement that interface in your class `NewJFrame` itself and validate `JTextField` value in `actionPerformed()` and delegate actual logic in some other method.

Use main method only as a n entry point to your program. Like `initComponents()` you can create methods to perform business logic, read files and create response to user actions. This way program will be easily readable and maintainable.

Also, `new NewJFrame().jTextField1ActionPerformed(null);` you used in `main()` does not make sense. You should only initialize JFrame once in a program. I think you should write only one statement in your `main()`method which is

```
new JFrame();
```

This will start your program and then your program must be driven by user actions.

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

The error is here:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
        new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream( file ), "UTF-8"
        )
);
```

file is an instance variable that cannot be accessed from a static method. You have to precede the file variable with the static keyword.

```
static File file;
```

instead of

```
File file;
```

Comment: Can you, please, write an example how to do it, or explain a bit more? I'm not sure, i understood what i have to do

Comment: This might fix the compilation error, but the program still won't work.

Comment: @Radiodef Let's have the program compile and take it from there. She will now be able to debug her program. Your downvote has indeed contributed to improve S.O. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for posting an answer which doesn't fix anything. You could, for example, explain why the compilation error happens, or explain that there is more that they need to do. Purely suggesting this is a waste of their time.

Comment: @Radiodef So sorry to have wasted your time :-(